# Use Webpage to Open it in Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I'm looking fora functionality that if you press a button or a link inside of a website, it will automatically open excel in you local computer. The button or link that you press is defined with specific data for instance data "test" and you want to have the data inside of the excel after you have pressed the button or link

Please remember that you have the data in the webpage and then when you press on the button or link you open the excel document and the data from the wepage will be transer automatically to the excel document.

Is it possible to do it? if yes, how?

I have tried finding a solution by using sourcecode but I failed.

Comment: I don't have a solution or sourcecode to find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ms-excel` scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Dn906146.aspx#sectionSection9) to open a file in Excel.

A simple example:

```
<a href="ms-excel:ofe|u|http://berkeleycollege.edu/browser_check/samples/excel.xls">
    Open in Excel
</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/mp0p1gcq/
Another demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/x9npn97z/

---

Full Syntax Definition for the `ms-excel` scheme:

> *Excel Scheme* =   "ms-excel:" *open-for-edit-cmd* | *open-for-view-cmd* | *new-from-template-cmd*
>
> *open-for-edit-cmd*    = "ofe|u|" *document-uri*
>   *open-for-view-cmd* = "ofv|u|" *document-uri*
>   *new-from-template-cmd* = "nft|u|" *template-uri* ["|s|" *save-location*]
>
> *document-uri* =   URI location of document to open
>   *template-uri*  =   URI location of template file upon which new file will be based
>   *save-location**   = URI location of folder in which new document should be created
>
> **save-location* is an optional parameter

Comment: If I understand that data is already containing in the excel document and not in the webpage?